# how to pass multiple request parameters in Spring?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

In my Spring Application i'm pass two request parameters to my business logic..

```
$.ajax({
        url : "classes/addResult",
        type:'POST',
        data : {"names":names,"globalClassId":globalClassId}

    });
```

And my business logic

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addResult", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addResult(ResultForm form,
        BindingResult result, Model model,
        @RequestParam("names") String[] names,
        @RequestParam("globalClassId") String globalClassId)
        throws Exception {
        -------------
        ------------
    return "";
}
```

But controller not calling to this method .. Why is their is any wrong my code..

Comment: If you receive `names` as `String` and decode it yourself, does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var names = new Array();
    $.ajax({
        url : "Result",
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            "names" : JSON.stringify(names),//or names.join()
            "globalClassId" : globalClassId
        }});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting error 400 (Bad request) ????????????

when you pass array data ({names:names} in your case ) to $.ajax() method then it append squre brackets [] after the paremeter name (means paremeter names will be names[] //not names)

therefor you need some changes in your code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addResult", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addResult(ResultForm form,
        BindingResult result, Model model,
        @RequestParam("names[]") String[] names, //replace names with names[]
        @RequestParam("globalClassId") String globalClassId)
        throws Exception {
        -------------
        ------------
    return "";
}
```

---

or you can use

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addResult", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addResult(ResultForm form,
            BindingResult result, Model model,
            @RequestParam("globalClassId") String globalClassId)
            throws Exception {
        String[] names = request.getParameterValues("names[]");//getting names array here
            -------------
            ------------
        return "";
    }
```